# preg_match: does not show any value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Not sure why it's not working. Simulated this regexp online at 
http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/
and it worked. But not in my PHP.

```
$val = 'IMG_BE0801s.jpg';
preg_match('/([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})/i',$val,$res);
print_r($res);
```

Please help.

Comment: The code you've shown does work. Prints `[0] => BE0801` for me. Maybe your input filenames are not what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

```
php> $val = 'IMG_BE0801s.jpg';

php> preg_match('/([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})/i',$val,$res);

php> print_r($res);
Array
(
    [0] => BE0801
    [1] => BE0801
)
```